# Issues with testing spring cloud streams service

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I am having issues testing my spring cloud stream service (which writes to a Kafka stream). It is based for the following [baeldung introduction](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-stream)

Here is the service code (with specifics omitted)

```
@Service
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class KafkaWriterService {

    @SendTo(Source.OUTPUT)
    public String write(String str) {
        return str;
    }

}
```

And here is the test

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class KafkaWriterServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private Source source;

    @Autowired
    private MessageCollector collector;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaWriterService service;

    @Test
    public void testMessages() {
        BlockingQueue<Message<?>> messages = collector.forChannel(source.output());
        service.write("FooBar");

        Object payload = messages.poll().getPayload();
        System.out.println(payload);
    }
```

Pretty straight forward, however when executing the test I get a NullPointerException as poll returns a Null.

Any idea what the issue may be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

If you're just looking for a Kafka producer example, then make the following changes to your service:

```
@Service
@EnableBinding({Source.class})
public class KafkaWriterService {

    private final MessageChannel output;

    public KafkaWriterService(@Qualifier("output") MessageChannel output) {
        this.output = output;
    }

    public void write(String str) {
        output.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(str).build());
    }
}
```

---

`@SendTo` requires a message source via `@StreamListener`.  It's used to transform an input message.

In your test program, no messages are being produced.

Change your code to the following in order to produce a message in your test:

```
@Service
@EnableBinding({Source.class, Sink.class})
public class KafkaWriterService {

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    @SendTo(Source.OUTPUT)
    public String write(String str) {
        return "Transformed: " + str;
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class KafkaWriterServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private Sink sink;

    @Autowired
    private Source source;

    @Autowired
    private MessageCollector collector;

    @Autowired
    private KafkaWriterService service;

    @Test
    public void testMessages() {
        BlockingQueue<Message<?>> messages = collector.forChannel(source.output());
        sink.input().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("Hello World!").build());

        Object payload = messages.poll().getPayload();
        System.out.println(payload);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used the code you've provided and it doesn't seem to be the issue, thank you for the advice though

Comment: I've updated my answer.  I noticed that no input messages were being produced, and there were no message listeners.  Fixing this using `Sink` and `@StreamListener` will allow you to successfully poll for a message in your test.

Comment: That's not the functionality I am implementing though. I want a service to write to a stream when the method is called not when a Sink it being written to, it's a valid use.

Also I am curious about your comment "@SendTo requires a message source via @StreamListener" I couldn't find any mention of that, can you point me to that?

Comment: It's in the sample here: https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/1609a9a5de267c69f26dc80027424a74d3e37fe6/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream/spring-cloud-stream-rabbit/src/main/java/com/baeldung/spring/cloud/stream/rabbit/MyLoggerServiceApplication.java#L27